# Sending emails once a cell has changed in Google SpreadSheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I need help with a script that I have created. I need to send an email to myself or manager any time cell "F" is changed to "Yes".  I think my code is okay, but I don't think my triggers are allowing me to complete the function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();

  var sendto = 'd.hammond@permasteelisagroup.com';
   if(cell.indexOf('F')!=-1){ 
      sendto = sheet.getRange('F'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
      }   
  var designer = '';
     designer = sheet.getRange('A' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  var assignment = '';
      assignment = sheet.getRange('B' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  var comment = '';
      comment = sheet.getRange('I' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() 
  var checked_by = '';
      checked_by = sheet.getRange('G' + sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()

  var mysubject = ss.getName() + ':' + 'Review Drawing: \n';
  var mybody = 'Please review: ' + assignment + ' \n' + 'Drawn by: ' + designer + '\n' + 'Please review any comments' + comment + ' \n' + 'Due by: ' + checked_by;


  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to:sendto, 
    subject:mysubject,
    body:mybody});
};
```

*

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Is the script completing?  In the VIEW menu, choose EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT, and look at the log print out.  At the bottom, it will state whether the code completed or not.  Tell us whether it completed or not. If not, what line is failing?  If it is completing, but you are not getting the expected results, then you need to debug the code.  We need the debugging information.  To debug, use `Logger.log('some description here: ' + variable_Name_here)`  Read the [troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting)

Comment: Please do what @sandygood suggested + can you remove your email from the code. That way if someone copies your code to use it and forgets to edit the email. You dont end up with lot of unnecessary emails :(